# Nginx not proxying calls to backend service

Tags: nginx, debian, proxy

I'm deploying an ReactJs project with React Router to a Debian Jessie system, together with an backend API node service running on port 3001.

Basically I need these rules:

All /api/* routes must be redirected t

- All /api/* routes must be redirected to localhost:3001
- The /graphql route must also be redirected to localhost:3001
- All other routes must redirect to /var/www/html/index.html, except for static files(images, etc).

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  root /var/www/html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location /api {
        proxy_redirect          http://localhost:3001/  /api;
        proxy_pass_header       Server;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_connect_timeout   5;
        proxy_read_timeout      240;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;

        proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:3001;
    }

    location /graphql {
        proxy_redirect          http://localhost:3001/  /graphql;
        proxy_pass_header       Server;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_connect_timeout   5;
        proxy_read_timeout      240;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;

        proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:3001;
   }


  location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
    expires -1;
    # access_log logs/static.log; # I don't usually include a static log
  }

  location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    expires 1y;
    access_log off;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
  }

  # Any route containing a file extension (e.g. /devicesfile.js)
  location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
  }

  # Any route that doesn't have a file extension (e.g. /devices)
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

Acessing `/api/*` routes are indeed being redirected to the proxy, but not the `/graphql` ones - All /graphql access is returning `404 not found`.

I'm much more a programmer person, so I'm stuck with this trying to deploy the project. Help appreciated...

Comment: Have you checked backend logs?

Comment: I'm not sure it's related to your problem, but it looks like your proxy_redirect's are dropping a "/" from the Location header.  Can you give an example of a full URL that you think is not being routed?  Do you know that the "~" locations have priority over the prefix locations?